# jQuery a smoother crossfade effect needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have (and need) one **on click** cycler-through-images and use this piece of code for this purpose:

```
$(".wrapper").on("click", function() {

    var $content = $(this).find(".content_stack");

    if ($content.length > 1) {

        var $curr = $content.filter(":visible");
        var $next = $curr.is($content.last()) ? $content.first() : $curr.next();

        $curr.fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $next.fadeIn(1000)
        })
    }
});
```

^ **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/couwga0s/)**

And I have also found on SO (and "adapted") an **automatic** "twin" for it:

```
$(".wrapper").each(function() {

  var $crossfade = $(this).find(".crossfade_square");
  var $zindex = -1;

  function loop() {
    ++$zindex;
    $crossfade.eq($zindex % $crossfade.length)
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(1000, loop);
  }
  loop();
});
```

^ **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru8tz96c/2/)**

**UPDATE**: Both are working as intended, separately. I need both of them (on click version and automatic version of cycling images). The codes are so different because I can't tweak either of them to work for both cases.:|

**The problem:** complete fade out>>fade in looks too distracting/"flickering"/"abrupt".

**I would greatly appreciate if someone can help me make the crossfade smoother/more subtle/...like one image is turning into another...**  (if it is possible without adding absolute/relative position in CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Use one function to loop and handle click event.</strike>
I split animation in to functions with queue of functions. If FadeIn being called by `.onclick` the queue is being cleared by `.stop(true)` method to stop animation and drop the queue.

```
$(".wrapper").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $curr = null,
        $crossfade = $this.find(".crossfade_square");
    var zindex = -1,
        length = $crossfade.length;

    function fadeOut() {
        if($curr)
        $curr.stop(true, false)
            .fadeOut(1000, fadeIn);
        else
            fadeIn();
    }

    function fadeIn() {
       ++zindex;
       $curr = $crossfade.eq(zindex % length)
           .fadeIn(1000)
           .delay(5000)
           .queue(fadeOut);
  }

  $this.on("click", fadeOut);

  fadeIn();

});
```

I have updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru8tz96c/50/) sample.

Comment: Hello!:) Thank you for the suggestion, but I need them both separately. I'll update my answer right now. Tha problem is fade out/fade in looking too "abrupt", not like a real crossfade...

Comment: works great and what's more - it adds click-control over an automatic cycling!!! Could I ask you (if it is possible) to tweak its fade effect, so images "turn" one into another without completely fading out and in (I really like the smoothness of CSS animation there http://jsfiddle.net/ru8tz96c/54/ , but can't use absolute/relative position)... If it's possible.... It would be an answer+++.

Comment: could fadeToggle make it look more like the CSS animation in the fiddle in my comment above?...or it will not make any difference?